# social game map tile storage

Tags: mongodb, game-engine

i am developping a prototype for a social game, i am using mongodb as the storage engine.
I am wondering if it is a good way to store the map tiles with tiles associated (states/type etc) in a mongo collection.

map : { 0: { type : grass, state: harvest, last_action_date : 2012-01-12 } 1: { ... } .... 44 : { ...} }

Maybe a flat file should be better? I don't know the best practise to store tile map in database like mongo.

That way i am able to fetch with one request, all the map tiles, and all states associated with tiles ... (each tiles is indexed with a number that permit to determinate the X/Y coordonate of the tile)

Does someone use this kind of system in mongodb?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Structure of the data in Mongo should be determined by how you will need to write, access, and / or modify that data.  Perhaps it makes sense to put the entire map in a single document as a double array of subdocuments (only practical for small maps).  Perhaps it makes more sense to store each tile of the map as a single document (this seems more likely).

If you store the tiles as individual documents then give them a common key like "map: 'map1'" so that you can pull the entire map at once.  Meanwhile, the power of storing the tiles as separate documents is you don't need to load the entire map at once.  Instead give each tile a common key like "map1" (so you can store multiple maps in the same collection), include an x and y coordinate (assuming 2d space), and create an unique index on the those three fields.  With this you can quickly and efficiently pull back only the tiles that you need to work with at any moment and drop from memory those that aren't necessary for your current calculations or presentation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My map requirements are small because this is for a social game usage. Given that my map won't be bigger than 60x60. I don't know yet the size of the associative  information related to tiles (states, time, etc) ... 

Understood for the index composed of the common key and x/y ... I keep this in mind if for some performance reasons i will have to change the storage system of the map...